# Is there a way to use \xmat* in the physics package to use upper indices?

Tags: matrices, physics

In the physics package, `\pmqty{}` gives a matrix with rounded brackets. Combining this with `\xmat*{}{}{}` allows you to choose a letter in the first argument, followed by number of rows and then by number of columns and it indexes them.

A minimal working example is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
$\pmqty{\xmat*{x}{4}{1}}$
\end{document}
```

Which gives the following output:

[image: matrix lower index]

The [documentation](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/physics/physics.pdf) doesn't specifically say that it can do upper indices, but I was wondering is there a trick to make it do this?

Otherwise would I have to try define a `\newcommand{\Xmat}` say, to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied the definition of `\xmatrix` as `\Xmatrix` and changed the `_` to `^`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{physics}
\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentCommand\Xmatrix{ s m m m }
{
    {
        \newtoks\matrixtoks
        \global\matrixtoks = {}
        \newcount\rowcount
        \newcount\colcount
        \loop
        \colcount = 0
        \advance \rowcount by 1
        {
            \loop
            \advance \colcount by 1
            \edef\addtoks{\ifnum \colcount = 1 \else & \fi #2 \IfBooleanTF{#1}{^{\ifnum #3 > 1 \the\rowcount \fi \ifnum #4 > 1 \the\colcount \fi}}{}}
            \global\matrixtoks = \expandafter{\the\expandafter\matrixtoks\addtoks}
            \ifnum \colcount < #4
            \repeat
        }
        \ifnum \rowcount < #3
            \global\matrixtoks = \expandafter{\the\matrixtoks \\ }
            \repeat
    }
    \the\matrixtoks
}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\Xmat{}{\Xmatrix}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\pmqty{\xmat*{x}{4}{1}}\cdot\pmqty{\Xmat*{x}{4}{1}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful answer, it works nicely! (+1) I was wondering though if I could to save from `\makeatletter` to `\makeatother` into another tex file, and then use `\include{name.tex}` would this work? It was just to save space?

Comment: Actually I found my problem, I should've used `\input` for the preamble, thanks! I'll accept the answer!

Comment: @snulty You are most welcome.  I have used up my permissible upvotes for today, but I will be voting up your question tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the `\xmatrix` macro to accept `^` alternatively to `*`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{physics}

\newtoks\matrixtoks % not inside the macro!!!!
\newcount\rowcount  % not inside the macro!!!!
\newcount\colcount  % not inside the macro!!!!

\DeclareDocumentCommand\xmatrix{ s t^ m m m }
 {%
  {%
   \global\matrixtoks = {}%
   \loop
   \colcount = 0
   \advance \rowcount by 1
    {%
     \loop
     \advance \colcount by 1
     \edef\addtoks{%
       \ifnum \colcount = 1
       \else
         &%
       \fi
       #3%
       \IfBooleanT{#1}{\sb{\ifnum #4 > 1 \the\rowcount \fi \ifnum #5 > 1 \the\colcount \fi}}%
       \IfBooleanT{#2}{\sp{\ifnum #4 > 1 \the\rowcount \fi \ifnum #5 > 1 \the\colcount \fi}}%
     }%
     \global\matrixtoks = \expandafter{\the\expandafter\matrixtoks\addtoks}%
     \ifnum \colcount < #5\relax
     \repeat
    }
    \ifnum \rowcount < #4\relax
      \global\matrixtoks = \expandafter{\the\matrixtoks \\ }%
    \repeat
  }
  \the\matrixtoks
 }
\DeclareDocumentCommand\identitymatrix{m}
 {%
  {%
   \global\matrixtoks = {}
   \loop
   \colcount = 0
   \advance \rowcount by 1
    {%
     \loop
     \advance \colcount by 1
     \edef\addtoks
      {%
       \ifnum \colcount = 1 \else & \fi
       \ifnum \colcount = \rowcount 1 \else 0 \fi
      }%
     \global\matrixtoks = \expandafter{\the\expandafter\matrixtoks\addtoks}%
     \ifnum \colcount < #1\relax
     \repeat
    }%
    \ifnum \rowcount < #1\relax
      \global\matrixtoks = \expandafter{\the\matrixtoks \\ }%
    \repeat
   }%
  \the\matrixtoks
 }

\begin{document}
$\pmqty{\xmat*{x}{4}{1}}\cdot\pmqty{\xmat^{x}{4}{1}}$
\end{document}
```

I took the occasion for fixing a few horrible mistakes in the macro: the `\newtoks` and `\newcount` declarations ***must*** be outside the macro, or a new token register and two counters would be wasted at each call of `\xmatrix` (which admits the shorthand `\xmat`). I also fixed `\identitymatrix` along the same lines.

Please, file a bug report.

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your help, and your answer. Apparently one can email comments and suggestions to: physics.tex@gmail.com. I'm not sure I understand the issue well enough to file a bug report. The macros are contained inside the package which latex loads? Would that mean it would be better to `\newtoks\matrixtoks` and `\newcount\rowcount ` and `\newcount\colcount` in the preamble for each document using the physics package?

Comment: @snulty The two affected macros are `\xmatrix` and `\identitymatrix`; with the code I showed, the error is fixed and the whole code should be used after loading `physics`. The package author should fix it in a similar way (maybe also accepting the suggestion for the `^` variant).